# Undoing a zip in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In Python, I can sort of get the "inverse" of a zip by giving back to zip

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = zip(a,b) # [(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)]
```

If instead I start with `c`, I can get `a` and `b` back using the following

```
c = [(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)]
a, b = zip(*c)
```

However, in Ruby, there seems to be only a `zip` method, and as such I'm not sure I can do this in exactly the same way...

Is there some sort of a similar nice idiom in Ruby for "unzipping" a list of lists?

---

I realize you could do

```
c[0].zip(*c[1..-1])
```

to essentially get semantically the same thing, but it doesn't look quite as intuitive this way...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Array#transpose](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose).

```
a = [1,2,3]
# => [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
# => [4,5,6]
c = a.zip(b) 
# => [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]

d, e = c.transpose
# => [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
d
# => [1,2,3]
e
# => [4,5,6]
```

Comment: use c.transpose.map(&:compact) in case nil gets filled while unzipping for missing corresponding indexed element.

Comment: @AlokAnand What do you mean by missing corresponding indexed element? If you talk about transposing an uneven array, e.g., `[[1,2],[3],[4,5]].transpose`, that yields `IndexError: element size differs (1 should be 2)` here. So unless the source has `nil` elements, I don't think the result of `transpose` can contain `nil`?

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers If you do, `[1,2,3].zip([4,5]) #=> [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, nil]]` then `[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, nil]].transpose #=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, nil]]` which is not the correct input. `#compact` will remove the nil from that result.

Comment: @LeoCorrea I see. But what if the input was actually `[4,5,nil]`? There is no way to know :) But fair enough, it can be useful to add `compact` in some situations. @Arup No, I don't use vim, why?